# A recruiter offered me "tree fiddy" salary package. What did he mean?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, recruitment, negotiation

A HR recruiter of a company(US based) DM-ed me on LinkedIn saying that he liked my profile & wanted to offer me a job. The job is in a field relevant to me. I am happy at my current job.

I Googled the company. It looked like a small to medium company. I replied back thanking him for taking the time out to go through my profile & showing interest in me. I then bluntly asked him about the salary package he would be offering so as to not waste each others time if the package is lower/same as my present job. But he replied **"tree fiddy"**. That's it. 
At first I though he made a typo, so I waited for him to respond. But he didn't.

I didn't understand what "tree fiddy" meant so googled it. It's a phrase from South Park(TV show), which I haven't seen. Upon searching further, I found that it means "Three Fifty" ($3.50). Some guy asks for "tree fiddy" ie $3.50 in a scene in South Park.

Did he make a joke about $3.50 being the salary package he's offering. I still don't get what the recruiter meant in my situation.

**What did the recruiter mean when he said "tree fiddy" to my salary package inquiry. How should I reply to this situation?**

Comment: Why don't you ask **him** for clarification?

Comment: I understand that he made a joke. What do I reply to this. I should have mentioned I am not a native speaker

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot possibly know what a person meant when they texted you. Ask them.

Comment: Hi @KharoBangdo -  To actually answer your question, "How should I reply to this situation?"  I would just hit reply and say "I do not understand what you mean."  If you don't hear back, just forget it altogether.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, at least in US no serious recruiter/HR will directly talk about proving a offer (rather than a interview) just by checking your linkedin profile. You are probably trolled, or maybe even worse, somebody may be trying to scam you.

Comment: I know it's you, Loch Ness Monster!!!

Comment: Someone offered you a job based solely on your Linkedin profile, without ever having an interview, not even a phone interview? This sounds extremely suspicious to me. I'd strongly suspect it's some kind of scam.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that you do not know how to respond to this? It should be common sense that if the person isn't serious then you shouldn't be either. The same rules about not believing everything applies to Linkedin as well unless there is a way to vet the person contacting you. Anyone could.

Comment: @Dan as mentioned in the OP, I was not aware of the reference he was making. Even after finding out the source of the reference, I didn't know its context. As mentioned by many, it could be a troll Or a scam.

Comment: https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/tree-fiddy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I then bluntly asked him about the salary package he would be offering so as to not waste each others time if the package is lower/same as my present job. But he replied "tree fiddy". That's it.

I live and work in the United States. I have never received such as unprofessional and, frankly, strange answer in response to a direct salary question. It could be a mistake, but it's not even close to an actual number.

My opinion is that you walk away the job opportunity and don't message the recruiter anymore. This job seems to be more trouble than its worth. This recruiter is not worth your time.

Answer (score 10):

"Tree Fiddy" is indeed a South Park meme, there are some clips of this on youtube with millions of views so it's quite well known.

Since you said you asked this recruiter bluntly what the salary package was this could be;

1: *A sarcastic reaction to your question.*

2: *A bad joke*

3: *The recruiter could be making fun of you.*

Or any combination of the above.

Either way it was an unprofessional response no matter which way you worded your question and you' do well to cross this one off your list and move on, no harm done.

One other last thought from me - Could it be someone you know? It's really odd to receive a job offer just from a Linkedin profile view without actually meeting or speaking to a candidate!

Comment: I agree. I can't imagine the person is legitimate; sounds way more like a friend playing a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he didn't like that you asked about salary straight away so gave you a sarcastic answer.

Either reply with a joke or don't reply at all.

Answer (score 1):

That probably depends on how much you want the job.

Personally, I would not reply.

He has seen your resume & thinks that you are good match. If he wants you, he will get back to you. If not, there’s plenty more fish in the sea.

After all, he approached you. It’s not as if you were actively looking.